# Chrome обманывает?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Есть таблица. Стала задача создать элемент, с точно таким же размерам столбца.

[Эксперимент 1](http://jsfiddle.net/nprWt/) - скрин на картинке, показана метрика у **th** и у **div**. Ширина задавалась через скрипт. **Ширины** выводятся на div, они **одинаковые**, но в *метрике*, ширина у th неожиданно **на 1 значение больше**.

[Эксперимент 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nprWt/2/)

**Chrome обманывает?**

**Как можно создать точно такую же таблицу, в позиции absolute, чтобы ширина столбцов совпадала?**

[image]

Comment: Вы бордер учитывали?

Comment: на картинке, показана метрика, border одинаковые, padding одинаковые, ширина - есть разница, но при наведении мышки ширина (тут уже с бордером и паддингом) одинаковая