# Фиксирование шапки таблицы при скролле

Tags: javascript

Есть [таблица](http://jsfiddle.net/LtH3c/1/) которая находится посередине страницы. Необходимо, чтобы при скролле сохранялась вся структура шапки таблицы "ширина ячеек".

Сейчас - таблица сразу же меняет свои размеры, так как ширина ячеек устанавливается автоматически.

Comment: надо при переходе в fixed устанавливать ширину ячеек заголовка циклом. **и не надо менять style на каждый скролл!**

Comment: @eicto и как же это реализовать?

Comment: Был уже такой вопрос. Не один в один, но [вот пример реализации][1]. Может пригодиться.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/jGaVU/6/

Comment: @Deonis в Chrome 29, Win7 шапка разъезжается

Comment: @Deonis аналогично и у меня.
только у меня код меньше в несколько раз

Comment: @DreamChild, у меня всё нормально (*Chrome 29.0.1547.76 m*). Баг на фиддле или локально тестили? И тут надо еще учесть то, что фиддл создавал топикстартер, стили, которые он скорее всего копипастил, могу быть лишними и влиять на работу, хотя почему результат у вас и у меня отличается - понять не могу.

@Виктор Евлампьев, по поводу "аналогично" - вы погорячились. Суть относящаяся к вашей задаче - вычисление размеров ячеек.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного по другому делал:

1. Клонировал только шапку; Ширину
2. Делал ей фиксированную позицию (left: позиция таблицы, top = 0);
3. Делал ее невидимой;
4. Как только скрол выходит за позицию верхней точки таблицы, показываю шапку.

Одна из проблем была в том, что разные браузеры по разному просчитывают ширину. 
[Вот топик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/241711/html-chrome-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82) на счет хрома, как он умеет обманывать

---

Вот функция, выкладываю так, для ознакомления, а не как готовое решение:

```
function drawAbsoluteRow()
{
    var tr = jQuery("#reportSummary-grid table thead tr");
    var tr_offset = tr.offset();

    // задаем div, на который будем вешать таблицу
    // div должен содержать прокрутку при необходимости
    // задаем ширину равною таблице
    var topRow = jQuery('<div>').addClass('grid-view').css({
        'padding': '0px',
        'overflow-x': 'auto'
    }).width(jQuery("#reportSummary-grid").width());

    // создаем div, на который повесим topRow
    // этот div необходим чтобы скрыть прокрутку
    var zRow = jQuery('<div class="redraw">').css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        'overflow': 'hidden',
        'left': tr_offset.left,
        'top': '0px'
    }).height(jQuery(tr).height());
    zRow.append(topRow);


    // задаем обработку прокрутки основной таблицы
    // чтобы прокручивалось синхронно нашего заголовка-таблицы
    jQuery('div.form').scroll(function(){
        jQuery(topRow).scrollLeft(this.scrollLeft);
    });

    // создаем нашу таблицу заголовок
    var topRowTable = document.createElement('table');
    topRowTable.className = 'items';
    jQuery(topRowTable).append('<thead><tr></tr></thead>');

    // tr_new - строка с нашей шапкой
    var tr_new = jQuery(topRowTable).find("tr");
    // дублируем весь html текст из исходной строки-шапки
    tr_new.append(tr.html());
    // находим все элементы th в исходной шапке
    var arrTh = tr.find('th');
    // находим все элементы th в нашей шапке
    var arr_th_new = tr_new.find("th");

    // для каждого элемента th из нашей шапки, чтобы задать ширину
    jQuery.each(arr_th_new, function(ind){
        // объект колонки у шапки основной таблицы
        var obj = jQuery(arrTh[ind]);
        // ширина
        var w = Math.round(obj.width());
        var br = jQuery.browser;
        if (br.chrome || br.opera)
            w = obj.innerWidth() - parseInt(obj.css('padding-left'), 10)*2;

        jQuery(this).css({
            'min-width': w,
            'max-width': w
        });
        jQuery(this).find('a').bind('click',function(){
            jQuery(arrTh[ind]).find('a').click();
            return false;
        }).prop('href','');
    });

    // добавляем таблицу в div
    topRow.append(topRowTable);

    // если скрол ниже, чем высота основной строки шапки, то отобразим нашу шапку
    if (window.pageYOffset < tr_offset.top)
    {
        zRow.hide();
    }

    // добавим на страницу наши заготовки
    jQuery("div.form").append(zRow);

    // при изменении размера окна, меняем положение нашей таблицы
    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        zRow.css('left', (tr.offset().left - window.pageXOffset + jQuery('div.form').scrollLeft())+'px');
    });

    // обрабатываем скролирование
    jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
        var tr_m = jQuery("#reportSummary-grid table thead tr");
        zRow.css('left', (tr.offset().left - window.pageXOffset + jQuery('div.form').scrollLeft())+'px');
        if (window.pageYOffset < tr_m.offset().top)
            zRow.hide();
        else
            zRow.show();
    });
}
```

Comment: А если ширина ячеек в шапке зависит от ширины ячеек в таблице? Разве в таком случае ячейки шапки не расползутся?

Comment: там отдельно я делал подгон ширины столбцов для шапки

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так:

1. Клонировал всю таблицу и добавлял ей `position: fixed;`
2. Убирал высоту у всех строк таблицы, кроме заголовка (`line-height:0; font-size: 0; ...`)

Таким образом размеры ячеек останутся нужными, а клон таблицы будет перемещаться за скроллом

Это далеко не лучший вариант решения, но другого я не нашел